# PHP API Erros For Binance

Tags: php, binance

I'm using PHP Binance Api (https://github.com/binance-exchange/php-binance-api)
I set up script with composer, and I set index.php file that's codes;

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// 1. config in home directory
$api = new Binance\API();
// 2. config in specified file
$api = new Binance\API( "somefile.json" );
// 3. config by specifying api key and secret
$api = new Binance\API("<api key>","<secret>");
// 4. config by specifying api key, api secret and testnet flag. By default the testnet is disabled
$api = new Binance\API("<testnet api key>","<testnet secret>", true);
// 5. Rate Limiting Support
$api = new Binance\RateLimiter(new Binance\API());
```

But my script giving this error;

> Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in C:\xampp\htdocs\binance\vendor\jaggedsoft\php-binance-api\php-binance-api.php on line 60

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What version of that library are you using? Also post the complete stack trace.

Comment: I'm using latest version

Comment: Looking at the repo you linked to, I don't see anything on line 60 in that file that could cause that specific error. Again, please post the complete stack trace. Also make sure which library you're using. Isn't it `jaggedsoft/php-binance-api`? The one you posted is just a fork of this one. Also double check the exact version and the code you have in your vendor.